# Make Mac ftpd default binary mode?

Tags: mac-osx, ftp

I made the mistake of purchasing a Brother MFC-9480CDW, a multi-function scanner printer. There is a "scan" button on the printer that you can configure to send a file to an FTP server. The problem that I am having is that the Brother does not put the FTP server into Binary mode, so RFC-compliant FTP servers receive the file in TEXT and new newline translation. This is causing the received PDFs to become corrupted.

I can't figure out how this could have happened. Perhaps the developers at Brother only tested this with FTP servers running on Windows? I have no idea. But anyway, I need to configure my FTP server (which is running on a Mac) to default to binary mode, not text. Alternatively I could run a different FTP server.

Anyone have a clue what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `vsftpd` from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).  According to the documentation in `vsftpd.conf`:

```
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
```

In other words, the default behavior of `vsftpd` is exactly what you want.